# Bootstrap popover click problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I add a table in my popover, and the initial value of"data-content" is "". When I first time click it, the popover will not pop, but "data-content" will have its value. And after that the popover will work normally.I don't know what's wrong with it.
Here's some js code:

```
 foo().then(function() {
      var table = "<table class='table table-bordered trans-table ng-scope ng-table'>" +
        "<tr>"+"<th></th><th></th><th></th>"+"</tr>";
      table += "</table>";
      $("#" + item.actionType + "_" + rowNum).attr("data-content", table);
      $("#" + item.actionType + "_" + rowNum).popover({html : true});
    });
```

Comment: can you please post the whole source code ?

Comment: it's in a project and too long to post...but here's html code

Comment: <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="showResetHistory(item, $index)" title="<h5></h5>" data-container="body" data-placement="left" data-content="" class="ng-binding">click</a>